# Unable to Sync Evernote?

Tags: sync, evernote

I have a new Samsung Galaxy Y, I am able to sync in GMail, Google Calendar and also completely use Google Maps, but I am not able to Sync in the Evernote App. What's Wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un-installing the App and Installing it back again, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Evernote has their own login-data which has nothing to do with your google-Account. Perhaps you just used the wrong password?